# 404 errors for the chunks files generated from @loadable/component

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering, loadable-component

My app is based on Reactjs SSR. I have few dynamic loadable components. I am using @loadable/component to achieve the same. I am using 'chunkExtractor.getScriptElements()' at the server side to load the files. Below is the build directory structure.

[build directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnlN0.png)

Localhost serves from the public directory. My app works fine but I’m getting 404 errors in network tab for the files in chunks folder. In browser it’s loading the .chunk.js files only. Why it’s not considering the files under chunk folders. How I can resolve this issue. I’m getting 404 errors in network tab for the files in chunks folder.